# Server is not Getting Data in Correct Format from Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, asp.net-mvc, ios5, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC at my Server. The Iphone is sending an Http Request to ASP.NET MVC Controller. Here is the Iphone Code,

```
-(void)addNSData:(NSData*)datapart inData:(NSMutableData*)POSTBody forkey:(NSString*)key
{
    [POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", datapart] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", POSTBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX/XXX/publish"]];

NSString *jsonFilePath = [[SharedData shareData].pageDataFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"page_json.json"];

[ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
 [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", POSTBoundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@".ASPXAUTH=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

// Add HTTP Body
 NSMutableData *POSTBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",POSTBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [self addNSData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localZipPath] inData:POSTBody forkey:@"zipFile"];
    [self addNSData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilePath] inData:POSTBody forkey:@"contents"];
    NSString *v = page.mo_page.version;
    [self addNSData:[v dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] inData:POSTBody forkey:@"version"];
    [self addNSData:[@"true" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] inData:POSTBody forkey:@"isActive"];
    [self addNSData:[page.mo_page.pageid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] inData:POSTBody forkey:@"directory"];

    // Add the closing -- to the POST Form
    [POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", POSTBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Add the body to the myMedRequest & return
    [request setHTTPBody:POSTBody];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error if any:%@",error.localizedDescription);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Response : %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:localZipPath error:nil];
    localZipPath = nil;
}
```

The ASP.NET MVC Server getting Data in this format, For example

```
Request.Form["Directory"]= "<32383862 33363339 36393538 34653463 62643862 35376561 66653135 35313764>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see ""<32383862...", this is what you will see if you as NSData for its 'description' (NSData *foo; ...; NSLog(@"FOO: %@", foo);). What you need to do is access the actual bytes by getting the length of the object and then the "bytes" pointer.

```
NSData *foo;
// set foo to some data object
NSUInteger len = [data length];
uint8_t *ptr = [data bytes];
memcpy(toSomeLocation, ptr, len);
```

Comment: You should look at your code, where you reference the data. Your code is as I said treating the NSData object as a string, and so its returning the NSString @"<3333 4444 5555 ....".

Comment: Thanks I have replaced,`[POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", datapart] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]` to `[POSTBody appendData:datapart];` and it works. Now it works But now the zipFile is null

Answer (score 2):

The content type "`multipart/form-data`" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

```
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", POSTBoundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

shouldn't that be "`application/json`" ? 
You're telling that your request contains binary data, and that's what the server expects, and that's what it gets.

Comment: Actually I have to submit file as well as other data. See above,     `[self addNSData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localZipPath] inData:POSTBody forkey:@"zipFile"]` . Actually, I need to do the same thing in Iphone that a normal browser send when you submit a multi-part form-data. I have test html page with multi-part form-data, which submit values(including file) in correct format in my ASP.NET MVC controller